# Compare an old file and new file, but ignore lines which only exist in new file?

Tags: text-processing, diff, join, file-comparison

I have two files:

1. `oldlist` - This contains a list of files and a md5 hash for each file. This was generated one year ago.
2. `newlist` - This also contains a list of files and a md5 hash for each file. However, some files have been changed (e.g. their md5 hash is different) and some new files have been added.

I would like to see all differences between `oldlist` and `newlist`, but I want to ignore any files which don't exist in `oldlist`.

That is, I don't care about new files. I only want to compare the md5 hashes for each old file, so that I can see if any files have changed within the last year.

I have tried [diff](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/diff/index.html) and [comm](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/comm-invocation.html), but have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/join.html) to combine matching lines from the two files. Assuming the file names come after the checksums (as in `md5sum` output) and don't contain whitespace, this will print all file names that are present in both lists, together with the old checksum and the new checksum:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 <(sort -k 2 oldlist) <(sort -k 2 newlist)
```

To also see new files, pass the `-a` option to `join`. A bit of output postprocessing will remove the file names for which the checksum has not changed.

```
join -a 2 -1 2 -2 2 <(sort -k 2 oldlist) <(sort -k 2 newlist) |
awk '$2 != $3'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with `awk` alone:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR   { o[$2]=$1; next }       !o[$2] { print $0, "NEW"; next } 
       $1!=o[$2] { print $0, "CHANGED" }' newlist oldlist
```

(Note that the supposed format of the files is `md5sum`'s output format: "md5  filename".)

**Update**: step-by-step explanation of how that `awk` one-liner works.

```
awk 'FNR==NR { # if current record number==overall record number (still processing the first file)
  o[$2]=$1     # store the record in array o: the key is the file name, the value is the md5
  next         # go to next record (do not execute the rest of the code)
}
# reaching this point means we are processing the second input file
!o[$2] {       # if array o not contains item with the current record`s file name
  print $0, "NEW" # print the current record and specify that it`s new
  next         # go to next record (do not execute the rest of the code)
}
# reaching this point means array o contains item with the current file name
$1!=o[$2] {    # if the current md5 is not equal with the md5 save for the current file name
  print $0, "CHANGED" # print the current record and specify it`s changed
}' newlist oldlist
```

Comment: nice answer, do you mind adding a small explanation of the awk program? For example that FNR==NR guards the action from applying to the 2nd file etc.

Comment: @maxschlepzig, I added the explanation. In case it not meets the SO standards and expectations I am open for suggestions to update it.

Answer (score 3):

if i'd understood your question correctly then `comm` can indeed do what you want. I'd suggest looking into `comm --help`

specificically

```
  -1              suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
  -2              suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
  -3              suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

so `comm newFile oldFile -1 -3` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the files looks like (space separated):

```
file1 md5sum1
file2 md5sum2
```

**Straightforward solution:**

```
# get only the files:
cut -f 1 -d " " oldlist > oldlist.files 

# from newlist, take only files which were also in the oldlist (updated files)
grep -w -F -f oldlist.files newlist > newlist.updated_files
```

And then you can just compare the two files (after sorting):

```
sort -u oldlist > oldlist.su
sort -u newlist.updated_files > newlist.updated_files.su
diff oldlist.su newlist.updated_files.su
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for an alternative, I've always used "`sdiff -s`" for comparing lists of files or md5sums.

Assuming the files are normal md5sum output "`md5hash  filename`".
Then either:

```
sdiff -s oldfile newfile | grep -v ">"
# sorting on the md5hash should help align and pick up renamed files.
sdiff -s <(sort oldfile) <(sort newfile)
```

Breaking this down:
`sdiff -s` : supress common lines, so exact matches are ignored. Shows `|`,`<`,`>` for differences.
`<(sort oldfile)` : does the command sort before the sdiff.
`grep -v ">"` : Ignore newfile entries. Only works if you don't have `>` in thefilename, which is unlikely anyway.

The width of `sdiff` can be altered to show longer lines `-w 100`.